# slight misunderstanding with sqlite database in android

Tags: android

i created a database with 6 columns and i have a create and update method in my class that takes 6 parameters/arguments which represent these columns. my problem is that, anytime i try to update or create the database without using all 6 arguments (setting some to null), i get an  error "constraint failed". this is most particular with the update method.

any ideas how i can get around this? because sometimes i don't want to fill all columns. I have removed the "text not null" constraint when creating the database.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to use the `ContentValues` to achieve this. Heres a quick demo.

My function

```
public boolean updateStuff(int id,ContentValues args) {
        return mDb.update(TableName, args, _id_col + "=" + id, null) > 0;
    }
```

And to call it. Note you can put as many ContentValues as you need

```
ContentValues initValues = new ContentValues();
initValues.put(col_key,col_value);
```

Edit:
`mDB` is a `SQLiteDatabase`

Comment: hey thanks! never thought of that. forgot, i could do such a thing.